# `error: no package available within package 'root'`

Tags: zig

I have the below app tree, where `rem` is a package that I want to build and use in my app:

```
[hasany@hasan-20tes1n300 html-txt]$ tree .
.
├── build.zig
├── rem
│   ├── rem.zig
│   ├── source
│   │   ├── dom
│   │   │   └── mutation.zig
│   │   ├── dom.zig
│   │   ├── named_characters.zig
│   │   ├── Parser.zig
│   │   ├── Tokenizer.zig
│   │   ├── token.zig
│   │   ├── tree_construction.zig
│   │   └── util.zig
│   ├── tools
│   │   ├── character_reference_data.json
│   │   └── generate_named_characters.zig
├── src
│   └── main.zig
└── zig-out
    └── lib
        ├── librem.a
        └── librem.so
```

The `zig-out` got generated after running the below `build.zig`:

```rs
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *std.build.Builder) void {
    const target = b.standardTargetOptions(.{});
    const optimize = .ReleaseFast;

    const exe = b.addExecutable(.{
        .name = "myexe1",
        .root_source_file = .{ .path = "src/main.zig" },
        .target = target,
        .optimize = optimize,
    });

    const lib = b.addStaticLibrary(.{
        .name = "rem",
        .root_source_file = .{ .path = "rem/rem.zig" },
        .target = target,
        .optimize = optimize,
    });
    lib.linkLibC();
    b.installArtifact(lib);
    exe.linkLibrary(lib);
    b.installArtifact(exe);
    const run_step = b.step("run", "Run the app");
    run_step.dependOn(&exe.step);
}
```

Ttrying to use it in the `src/main.zig` as `const rem = @import("../zig-out/lib/rem");` but got the error `error: no package named '../zig-out/lib/rem' available within package 'root'`